# node.js domain memory leak

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, node.js-domains

I attach a new domain to each incoming request in my Express app, just like in the [example in the node.js doc](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_explicit_binding).

However, I noticed I was leaking memory. When I do a [heapdump](https://www.npmjs.org/package/heapdump) and inspect it in Chrome, I notice that classes that should be garbaged immediately are actually retained by old domains.

Is there something I should do to tell node.js not to keep old domains ?

Comment: domains are an event emitter, and usually have at least one error event listener..at the end of the request/response cycle, you need to remove all listeners of that domain instance to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

domain.exit()

The exit method exits the current domain, popping it off the domain stack. Any time execution is going to switch to the context of a different chain of asynchronous calls, it's important to ensure that the current domain is exited. The call to exit delimits either the end of or an interruption to the chain of asynchronous calls and I/O operations bound to a domain.

If there are multiple, nested domains bound to the current execution context, exit will exit any domains nested within this domain.

Calling exit changes only the active domain, and does not alter the domain itself. Enter and exit can be called an arbitrary number of times on a single domain.

If the domain on which exit is called has been disposed, exit will return without exiting the domain.

Comment: I was looking at the source, it seems like you should remove all listeners on the domain, as well as calling `d.exit()`.